# Need help with some complex SQL query

Tags: mysql

I need some help with a complex SQL query. Here's my setup: there are two tables, one with authors, and another with books. The books table contains a field named "author" which holds author's id. If a book has more than one author, then the "author" field will contain all the authors ids separated by ";" (something like 2;34;234).

On the website I have to list all the books written by an author. If there's only one author, its simple, but how can I get those books where the author I'm interested in is the second or third author?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of bad table design. Ideally you would have 3 tables `books`, `books2authors`, `authors`.
`books2authors` would hold `book_id` and `author_id` and thus one book can have more authors and you can easily work with them in SQL.

If you can't change the design, then I would go with getting all the books, parsing the `author_id` field and if you want to get only the second author, issue extra query `select * from authors where id = <second_author>` to get the info you need.

Comment: Thanks for the table design lesson! I might have to use it in a project I'm currently working on that has an unknown number of options for each entry.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, change the schema.  Try a lookup table with AuthorPosition, like so:

```
BookID  AuthorID  AuthorPosition
1       1         1
1       2         2
1       4         3
2       3         1
2       1         2
```

Then, if you need the second author, you can query for AuthorPosition = 2.

If you can't change the schema, you can get all the books (maybe even use a LIKE query, though I'm not sure how), then parse in business code the authors you want.

Comment: I think he can simplify it by just having a Map table with `BookID` and `AuthorID` as columns.  He gave the example "I'm interested in is the second or third author" to illustrate the point, not because he'll have to search on "AuthorPosition = 2" any time soon.  I hope, at least.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the schema to use an interesection table (e.g., `BooksAuthors`), then something like the following should work:

```
...
where AuthorID = '42' 
    or AuthorID = '42;%' 
    or AuthorID = '%;42;%' 
    or AuthorID = '%;42'
```

Only the first two of these clauses can make use of indexes though, so searches for authors other than the first will be slower.

Comment: You are correct, this will be *painfully* slow on a medium-sized table. If at all possible, an intersection table should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the DB tables?

You should really put the book and author IDs in a table of their own (a join table).

This table (maybe called book_author) would just have the IDs for the Books and the Authors so you can perform queries like:

```
select a.* from book b, book_author ba, author a
where 
    b.id == ba.book_id
    and
    a.id == ba.author_id
    and 
    b.id = 123;
```

to return all authors for book with id 123.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you make a small change: replace the ; separator with , (comma).
Then you can do this:

```
select b.*
from authors a
inner join books b on find_in_set(a.id, b.author) >0;
```

This is a good example of nightmares given by bad design. The query should work, but it will always perform full table scans (terribly slow when the tables grow bigger).